# What does ?. mean in Kotlin when used on the left side of an assignment?

Tags: kotlin

According to the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), the ?. operator represents a 'safe call', meaning that if it's used in a chain of method calls, the entire chain will return null if the value of whatever it's used on is null.

But what about if it's used on the left side of an assignment? Since the left side isn't the side that's 'returning' anything it seems like it probably has a different effect. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
val myObj = SomeObj()
myObj?.property = SomeClass.someFunc() // What does ?. do in this context?
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It means that if one of the safe calls on the left-hand side fails (i.e. its receiver is null), then the whole assignment is skipped, and the expression on the right-hand side is not evaluated at all.

```
val nullable: Container? = null
nullable?.x = f() // f is not called
```

<sup>[(runnable demo)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/53p2po3gng5ln7rjavo30fagri/ept2e273e4nbv121jqrbhv88er)</sup>

Comment: That's interesting because in the case where you're assigning something to a value based off itself, you still have to use it on the right side as well to avoid a compiler error. (e.g. myObj?.property = myObj?.property + 1)

Comment: @Sonofblip, there's a different reason for that: in a multi-threaded environment (which a JVM is), a global variable `myObj` can be reassigned between the check in the left-hand side and the evaluation of `myObj?.property` in the right-hand side. So, you need to check it again.

Comment: @hotkey sir, first up-vote. but it needn't to check it again in multi-threads since the kotlin copy the reference into another variable.

Comment: @holi-java, please see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/37e95db4243ccd0e8a012733a5982413), where I explained the bytecode generated for a line `c?.x = (c?.x ?: 0) + 1`. You can clearly see that `AppKt.c` is accessed twice, so if `c` is reassigned inbetween, you can get a null in the second call. Therefore the compiler treats that `c` as nullable in the right-hand side, and you should check it for null again to be able to use it. That's what I meant.

Comment: Also, as a funny side-effect, in a statement `c?.x = (?.x ?: 0) + 1`, you can set `x` of a different object than the one you get it from. :)

Comment: @hotkey sir, but what are you  said is that you need check the `myObj` again rather than the `property` of `myObj`.

Comment: @holi-java, I meant, if `c` is nullable, the Kotlin compiler does not let you write `c?.x = c.x + 1`, because `c` is accessed twice, and it can be reassgined inbetween. By '*check*', I mean that you have to use safe access `?.` in the right-hand side again, like `(c?.x ?: 0) + 1`, or make a not-null assertion `!!`, like `c!!.x + 1`.

Comment: @hotkey I'm sorry, I understand what are you said by your detailed comment. thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing a fun question & answer in Kotlin just now. Even if the answer is very nice, but I want to clarify it in more detailed.

The assignment expression below:

```
myObj?.property = SomeClass.someFunc()
```

is transformed to Java bytecode by Kolin as below:

```
val it = myObj;

if(it != null){
   it.property = SomeClass.someFunc(); 
}
```

so there is no problem in multiple threads. It still works fine and I have tested it on [github](https://github.com/holi-java/kotlin-guides/blob/55911cced7dc8d35d692bac05d62196e31a8fbbf/src/test/kotlin/com/holi/basic/operators/NullSafetyOperatorsTest.kt#L46-L62). But it will result in the [Thread Interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html) problem, which means it will modify the `property` on different references when `myObj` is changed.

Except the assignment expression can be *short-circuited*, others also can be *short-circuited*. For example:

```
val array:Array<Any>? = null;

//   v--- short-circuited
array?.set(0,SomeClass.someFunc());
//                     ^--- never be called
```